# Extending ContactsController and ContactDataModel for List Manager Fields

Tags: sitecore-client, exm, list-manager

**Version:** `Sitecore 9.2`

I have added a column `Title` in core `sitecore/client/applications/list manager/lists/contact` list and added `DataField` as `Personal_Title` (built-in facet). But data does not show up. Am I using the incorrect facet key or do I need to extend this for OOTB facets too?

Is there a way to extend `Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.ContactsController.GetEntities()` to override the `ContactDataModel` used to include an OOTB facet or custom-built facet so one may include this the List Manager Contact List?

I.e. 
[image]

Comment: I think this question is already covered in the answer to your last question. Didn't these blogs helped:https://kbdocssitecore.wordpress.com/2020/03/19/display-custom-contact-facet-data-in-sitecore-contact-list/.
I have added an answer to your comment in the post there. I hope it helps.

Comment: ContactsController is different in 9.2 no?

Comment: Not sure. I do not have Sitecore 9.2 installed. I will try and get back to you once I install and try the same on Sitecore 9.2.

Comment: How can the older question be the duplicate?? lol